# jQuery .delay doesn't work

Tags: jquery

This is very weird. I have a div and I want that div to slideDown in 5 seconds. So I'm using this script:

```
$('.land_leadform').hide(0).delay(5000).slideDown(5000);
```

If I use `.delay(5000)` the animation doesn't work at all. But if I use

```
$('.land_leadform').hide(0).slideDown(5000);
```

it works fine.

What could be the reason for `.delay` not to work? Is this a known issue or something?

Comment: hide() is not an animation.. delay can only be used for animations

Comment: Seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/w2fCX/

Comment: your first code is working absolutely fine and i had no issues with that whatsoever.see this here:  http://jsbin.com/oliqod/1/edit

Comment: @kayen: Your link does not work properly, due to configuration. See fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/w2fCX/1/

Answer (score 1):

`.delay` only works when you're dealing with the animation queue. `.hide()` and `.show()` without arguments don't interact with the animation queue. By adding the `.hide(1)` and `.show(1)` before the `.delay()` makes the slide animations wait on the queue.