# jquery delay function executes immediately

Tags: jquery, delay

Why does

```
$(this).addClass('animate').delay(5000).removeClass('animate');
```

not work? It doesn't seem to delay removeClass and just removes the class immediately

Comment: why you need delay here? Didnt get the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [jQuery .delay doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392014/jquery-delay-doesnt-work)

The delay function only works on the animation queue. The addClass/removeClass arent' part of that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following code, since `.delay()` only works with animation,

```
var _this = $(this).addClass('animate');

setTimeout(function(){ 
  _this.removeClass('animate');
},5000);
```

Comment: Yes I know about setTimeout but why doesn't jquery's delay function work? The documentation says it delays everything in the queue

Comment: @user1008134 But nothing here is in the queue..! :\